# Does "vector<x>::iterator" mean there is a "vector<x>" namespace?

Tags: c++, stl

I have seen the code

```
vector<char> v(10);
vector<char>::iterator p;
```

here what is the need of `vector<char>::`.Does it mean iterator is a class inside vector namespace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does it mean iterator is a class inside vector namespace?

Not quite, is a **type** inside `vector` **class** template. The iterator not only depends on the type of container (here a `vector`), but on the type of element iterated over as well (here a `char`).

Comment: `vector<char>::iterator` need not be a class. What we can say is that it's a nested type. Perhaps add a small example of such a type?

Comment: @K-ballo @Luc Danton I was thinking that only static members can be accessed using `::` operator.I was unaware of nested types .Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Vaysage: You are thinking the wrong way around. Non static member variables are accessed via `.`. All other members of the class are accessed via `::`

Comment: @Tux-D: The difference is that `.` is for member access via an object (or rvalue), whereas `::` is the scope resolution operator. So for example, member functions can be accessed using `object.func` or `Class::func`, depending on context. See 3.3.6/2 ([basic.scope.class]) in C++03.

Comment: @K-ballo: to be precise, `vector` is a class template, not a template class. You can probably call `vector<char>` a template class if you like, since it is a class and it's a specialization of a template. But since `vector` isn't a class, it causes a lot of confusion when people call it a "template class". Same thing for function templates.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly the easiest way is to understand that `::` is the scope operator, not just for namespaces.

`std::vector<char>` is a class, and therefore it has its own class scope (3.3.6 in C++03, 3.3.7 in C++11). `std::vector<char>::iterator` is a fully-qualified name in that scope. In the case of `iterator`, it names a type -- not necessarily a class, and even if it is the class itself is not necessarily defined in `std::vector<char>`, since `iterator` could be a typedef.

As it happens, a class scope is not one of those things that C++ calls a "namespace". In everyday[*] English, you could describe it as a kind of namespace, it just isn't the proper terminology in C++.

However you call it, though, be aware that it's `vector<char>` which is the class, and has the scope that contains `iterator`, not `vector`. `std::vector` does guarantee that any `vector<T>` has an `iterator` type, but for other templates it is not necessarily the case that every specialization has the same members and nested types. So there is no `vector` scope.

[*] "everyday", if your days are the kind of days had by people who talk a lot about namespaces.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does mean exactly that. Iterator is defined within the scope of the class `vector`, and for each different type a `vector` is created, there's a different implementation of the iterator as well.

Comment: Not exactly, since he thinks `vector` is a namespace.

Comment: `vector` is neither a class nor a namespace.

Answer (score 1):

It also means that the iterator operates on a `vector<char>` instead of, say, a `vector<int>`.

Answer (score 0):

Namespaces cannot be templetized, so vector cannot be a namespace.
In fact vector is a template class (and vector is an instantiation) for which iterator is a nested type.

But the question has some point: the A::B syntax is normally not distinguishable. In term of name resolution, if fact, both classes an name-spaces are ... container of names.

Classes are more than name containers: they represent data having instances and associated functionalities.
Namespaces are just container for names